# Is there a way in OPA to only evaluate policies relevant to certain request?

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I'm experimenting with OPA and securing HTTP REST API. I want to implement ABAC authorization. My question is if it's possible to create rules in such a way that only those relevant to the request will be evaluated - a kind of Target element in XACML

Consider two policies:

```
package entity

default allow = false

allow = true {
    input.method == "GET"
    input.path = ["entity", "1"]
    input.subject.location = 1
    input.subject.role = "admin"
    input.resource.location = 2
}
```

```
package user

default allow = false

allow = true {
    input.method == "GET"
    input.path = ["users", user]
    input.user = user
}
```

And a request for decision:

```
{
  "input": {
    "method": "GET",
    "path": [
      "entity",
      "1"
    ],
    "subject": {
      "location": 1,
      "role": "admin"
    },
    "resource": {
      "location": 2
    }
  }
}
```

What am I getting:

```
{
  "result": {
    "entity": {
      "allow": true
    },
    "user": {
      "allow": false
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to get:

```
{
  "allow": true
}
```

In this example, a decision request contains only data relevant to the policy with entity. My question is if there's a way to configure OPA or Rego policies so only the relevant policies are evaluated without specifying the policy in the decision request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get back depends on what you ask for :) When querying OPA through its [REST API](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/rest-api/#get-a-document-with-input), this is decided by the path of the request, i.e. `/v1/data/entity/allow`, or `/v1/data/user/allow`. If you want to decide dynamically which policy or rule(s) to evaluate, you'd commonly setup a "main" policy, which routes to the relevant policy or rule based on the input data. See this article on [dynamic policy composition](https://www.styra.com/blog/dynamic-policy-composition-for-opa/) if that's what you're after.

Comment: Thanks! I know it’s crazy but I wanted to check if I can use OPA to build a dynamic permission system that allows users to define who can do what on which resource. So the problem is that I will have a lot of policies that I will need to refer to and route by inputs. I guess it’s just simply not designed for my use case. Not only I would need to build some translation layer between UI and Rego which already sounds really odd, but also I might have problems with the performance of those policies. It's a pity as OPA looked really tempting, also because of its partial query eval functionality.

Comment: I guess it depends on how complex those policies would be, but what you want to achieve is often doable by having a fairly static policy, with highly dynamic _data_ provided e.g. per resource. SO comments aren't the best place for that discussion, but ping me on the OPA Slack if you want to continue that discussion :)